# how to replace multiple occurrences of single special character with different characters

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a code which has a string with a special character `","` in it. It can have either one occurrence or multiple occurrences.

Now what I want to do is I want to replace every special character with characters `[a-z]`. Every single special character should be replaced with every character with characters `[a-z]`.

After everytime the special characters are all replaced I will check the string for a property, if it satisfies that property, the program should terminate and the string will be returned.

For example take input as : `hello,,how`

I want to replace first `","` with `'a'` and second `","` with `'a'` first and then with `a,b` then with `a,c ..... a,z` till `z,a......z,z`. (If in this process a string turns out to obey my required property, that string will be returned)

The above example hello,,how would produce these strings - hellowaahow , hellowabhow, hellowachow..... hellowazhow, ...... hellozahow,hellowzbhow, hellozchow......hellozzhow. If any time in this process a string satisfies a property that string will be returned and program will exit

I don't even have an idea how to approach this problem, can anyone help me out with an efficient technique?

Comment: Are there some constraints known to you like maximum string length, maximum occurance of the special character `,`?

Comment: Most of what you need is in the [Javadoc for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). That and a nested loop or two is all it takes. (Yes, this can be done easily with Streams but that's a bit advanced for this.)

Comment: you can consider length of string to be below 25,000 always including maximum occurrences of special character(it can have any number of occurrences below 25,000), i.e can even have a string like  ,,,,,,,,,  and i would replace all the special characters with every character like I mentioned in the problem.

Comment: Can you please show the result you expect for the example you gave, because I read it as: *replace first "," with 'a'* which will give `helloa,how`, then *replace second "," with 'a' first and then with a,b* which will give `helloaaa,bhow`. That just seems wrong, so please show what you expect, and maybe also what you expect for 3 or 4 commas.

Comment: hello,,how - hellowaahow , hellowabhow, hellowachow..... hellowazhow, ...... hellozahow,hellowzbhow, hellozchow......hellozzhow. If any time in this process a string satisfies a property that string will be returned and program will exit.

Comment: So you are telling that if string length is ```25000``` OP Strings will be ```25000*25000```. Am I right?

Comment: max string length is 25000 , the special characters are also part of string.

Answer (score 0):

> help me out with an efficient technique

You need to keep track of what's the next replacement string:

```
String nextReplacement = "a";
```

Also keep track of the next letter:

```
char nextLetter = 'b';
```

Go through the string character-by-character. When you see a comma, insert `nextReplacement`, append `","+nextLetter` to `nextReplacement`, and increment `nextLetter` if you have not reached `z` yet.

If you see a non-comma character, insert it into the output without a change.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it right away, btw this ","+nextLetter would still have "," in it doesnt it? I want to replace that "," but appending would just add the character to the comma wont it? sorry if i'm wrong, i am a bit new to programming

Comment: An important part of this, that isn't mentioned, is that you should use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build the result, so when answer says "insert" it means to call the `append()` method.

Comment: @Revanth Input side should be separate from the output side, so your code that reads the input should not see that additional comma.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry, i didnt understand? I beg your pardon, this is the first question I'm asking on stackoverflow, so I don't know all the rules..